# CSS Media Queries not working on iPhone

Tags: iphone, css, media

I am having trouble with my css media queries. They work great on the computer but don't work on my iPhone. Here is what i have:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .logInCenter{
        width:90%;
        left:0;
        top:0;
        margin-left:0px !important;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 768px) {

    .fluid-half
    {
        display:block;
        padding:20px 0px;
        width:100%;
        float:none;
    }

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 991px) {

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {

}
```

The problem is that my iPhone only detects the styles when I put them in the third media query. The issue is that at 100% width, it looks just like any other desktop site. Really far away. I hope that makes sense! thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have you made sure that the following code is in your HTMl head? Tells the devise to look at viewport sizes.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Comment: I totally forgot about his. Thanks for the reminder, it works!

Comment: This answer deserves more upvotes and prominence in search. I, too, was missing the `viewport` meta tag and wish I had found this answer sooner!

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using css media queries, you should not use meta tag in your html file.
You can set the same in css using:

```
@viewport {
   width: device-width;
   zoom:1;
}
```